# PHP detect repeated word

Tags: php, detect

Is it possible to detect a repeated word from this string :

```
$string = "dogdog";
```

I want a return of "str" only and not "strstr"

I tried some good solution but it won't really do how i want it to be done :

```
$string = "dogdog";
$length = strlen($string) / 2;
 echo substr($string, $length);
```

I want it to be detected **from a big sentence** ( $string = "*dogdog* something *dogdog* else bla bla, something, ( something ); something"; )....*String contains 2 repeated **Correct** words without separation*, How is it to detect and fix it to a real single word?

Comment: Q: What do you mean by "repeated"?  That "strstr" has the string "str" twice?  Q: If so, what about "st/st" etc?  What is a "word"?  For example, is "strstr abc def" three words?

Comment: What about "aaaaaaaa" - would it return just "a"? And what about "aabbaa", would it return "ab"? That's how I understand it, if you want to return "str" from "strstr".

Comment: Please provide sample inputs/outputs. For example, "this is a longlong sentence" => "this is a long sentence", "strstr" => "str", "strstrstr" => "str", "one twotwo threethreethree" => "one two three". Are all of these correct?

Comment: @Wrikken:  Is three weeks a long, long time ago?  (Gosh, I must be ancient.  :-)

Comment: @paulsm4 A: Yes that's what i mean (wordword) you see, word is repeated twice in the same line without separations, i want to detect that and fix it to return as a single word 

A: Nope, it might and might not have any separations, " strstr abc def " is supposed to be 3 words only if i had the ability to detect strstr is repeated to fix it to str only

Comment: @Osa, what would be "strstr abc str def"? And what would be "strstr abc strstr def"? And "dj bobo"? I don't exactly get what you're trying to do, if there "might and might not be any separations".

Comment: @binaryLV The string will only contain correct words, as example "catcat" in case which wont happen that aaaaa was detected then ignore, however, in my case, it will only contain correct words and not shuffled letters

Comment: @Osa, by saying "the string will only contain correct words" you mean that you have some kind of dictionary (array) with valid words? And how is "str" supposed to be a valid word? :)

Comment: "correct words" That's where it will get tricky

Comment: @binaryLV "**str** abc str def" , "**str** abc **str** def", "dj **bo**", however as i said in the previous comment, in my case, it will only contain correct words and not shuffled letters

Comment: @binaryLV just an example, this is what came up my mind, ill edit though

Comment: Without using a dictionary, there is no point in doing it without spaces. E.g. this is classed classed as a repeat

Comment: I'm thinking about something like `$str = preg_replace("\W({$wordList}){2,}\W", "\1", $str)`, where `$wordList` would be something like `cat|dog|door|house|family`...

Comment: The edits to the question result in it making even less sense now.  In your new example sentence, what is the desired output?

Answer (score 0):

[`explode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)/[`preg_split`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) your sentence into an array of words, and then use your technique on each word.

You haven't specified what constitutes a "word"; this will determine precisely what delimiters you will need to explode on.

Comment: this will be a bit complicated, the sentence wont only contain spaces

Comment: @Osa: Ok, so maybe naive exploding based on `' '` won't be sufficient, but the essential idea will be the same.  You haven't specified what else might be in your sentence, so you will have to figure out what other delimiters you will need to introduce.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth see the OPs comment above.

Answer (score -1):

You should do this iteratively. Here's a start:

```
//turn punctuation into something we can split on
$sanitized = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9]+/i', '_', $string);
$words = explode("_",$sanitized);

//now that you have a 'clean' array, do logic
foreach($words as $word) {
    //tinker with word dup' logic here.
}
```

Comment: the thing, sentence won't only contain a space, it will contain more than one kind of symbols to explode which is really complicated, also, strstr could be found in multiple places.. i just edited the sentence

Comment: @Osa: Why is it a problem if a word appears in multiple places in the sentence?